# Several issues while trying to write the same code from another project

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

The teacher from my Java-coding class has published on his web page an example of what he expects us to code for ourselves. When I tried to recreate the same code within my own lab, however, I have been facing several errors. Here is the code:

```
public class StudentRepositoryImpl extends Repository<Student, Long> implements StudentRepositoryCustom {
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StudentRepositoryImpl.class);

public StudentRepositoryImpl()
{
    super(Student.class);
}

@Override
@Transactional
public List<Student> findAllWithLabsSqlQuery()
{
    log.trace("findAllWithLabsSqlQuery: method entered");

    HibernateEntityManager hibernateEntityManager = getEntityManager().unwrap(HibernateEntityManager.class);
    Session session = hibernateEntityManager.getSession();

    Query query = session.createSQLQuery("select distinct {s.*}, {sd.*}, {d.*}" +
            " from student s" +
            " left join student_lab sd on sd.student_id = s.id" +
            " left join lab d on d.id = sd.lab_id")
            .addEntity("s", Student.class)
            .addJoin("sd", "s.studentLabs")
            .addJoin("d", "sd.lab")
            .addEntity("s", Student.class)
            .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
    List<Student> students = query.list();

    log.trace("findAllWithLabsSqlQuery: students={}", students);
    return students;
}

@Override
@Transactional
public List<Student> findAllWithLabsJpql() {
    log.trace("findAllWithLabsJpql: method entered");

    javax.persistence.Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery("select distinct s from Student s" +
            " left join fetch s.studentLabs sd" +
            " left join fetch sd.lab d");

    List<Student> students = query.getResultList();

    log.trace("findAllWithLabsJpql: students={}", students);
    return students;
}

@Override
@Transactional
public List<Student> findAllWithLabsJpaCriteria() {
    log.trace("findAllWithLabsJpaCriteria: method entered");

    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Student> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Student.class);

    query.distinct(Boolean.TRUE);

    Root<Student> from = query.from(Student.class);

    Fetch<Student, StudentLab> studentLabFetch = from.fetch(Student_.studentLabs, JoinType.LEFT);
    studentLabFetch.fetch(StudentLab_.discipline, JoinType.LEFT);

    List<Student> students = getEntityManager().createQuery(query).getResultList();

    log.trace("findAllWithLabsJpaCriteria: students={}", students);
    return students;
}
```

}

The errors I am facing are:

1 - the super method ("Cannot resolve method 'super(java.lang.Class)'")

2 - every getEntityManager function ("Cannot resolve method 'getEntityManager'")

3 - the "Student_" and "StudentLab_" ("Cannot resolve symbol")

In his project the same code, albeit with class name modifications, works. Is it something to do with the .iml or pom.xml files?

Here are the imported libraries:

```
    import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.jpa.HibernateEntityManager;
import org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryImpl;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import javax.persistence.criteria.*;
import java.util.List;

import ro.ubb.books.core.model.*;
import ro.ubb.books.core.repository.*;
```

Comment: You have to import the required libraries.

Answer (score 0):

If you have also copied pom.xml, try running following command.

```
mvn clean package
```

Note : mvn(maven) must be installed.

Comment: In which folder do I need to run this command from? The folder where the pom.xml file is located, or the folder for the whole project?

Comment: That didn't seem to fix the issue. The same errors persist.